# User Profile Images - where are resize and compression quality settings?

Tags: user-profile, image

I am in the process of uploading staff photos onto their profiles and I have been absolutely horrified at the way Sharepoint resizes/compresses these images.

Even when I upload the images at the native resolution of 144px X 144xp (which gives the best results on the Profile page because the image doesn't have to be resized by Sharepoint first), the two smaller thumbnail images generated by Sharepoint still look terribly degraded as a result of the resize/compression process.

Does anyone know how I can reconfigure the settings in Sharepoint to give a better, cleaner resize/compression result - ideally, if I upload an image larger than 144px X 144px, so I don't have to bring every photo into Photoshop to resize it before uploading it?

Thanks! :-)

Luke

Comment: Apparently, Sharepoint creates three resized versions of the original uploaded image: 144px, 96px and 32px in 2010 (or 300px, 72px and 48px in 2013).  You can find these newly generated, renamed and resized images in the folder structure if you look for them.  I had considered simply going straight into this folder structure and uploading images created outside of Sharepoint to replace them, but this isn't practical or efficient in the long-term.

Comment: The closest discussion that I've been able to find on the subject is here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d5366ca7-c1f5-4689-a2f1-eef2a35fbeba/sharepoint-mysites-picture-quality?forum=sharepointadmin

I'm ideally looking for a settings change somewhere within Sharepoint to resolve this (looking unlikely at this point), or some kind of 3rd party software that can create these 3 sizes of image quickly and easily (without the need for coding/scripting expertise) and in better quality than Sharepoint seems to be able to generate them.